# Centre align div content in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want my date picker to be in the middle of the page, eg. the line where I have: `<div class="center-block text-center datepicker"></div>`

Obviously `center-block` and `text-center` I tried already - but neither change anything. And with the offset it just makes it close to the centre without being perfectly centre aligned.

What do I need to do?

Thanks

```html
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-sm-12'>
    <div class='page-header page-header-with-icon mg-t'> <i class='fa-icon-calendar'></i>

      <h2>Calendar</h2>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
        <div class="center-block text-center datepicker"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What ended up working was `<div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4" align="center">`

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="datepicker"></div>
</div>
```

Then give the date picker something like:

```
.datepicker {
   display:inline-block;
   margin:0 auto;
}
```

I haven't tested this, but it would be where I would start.

Answer (score 1):

`style="text-align:center;"` shall do the trick no?  I tested and for me, the "CALENDAR" text is centered

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
   <div class="page-header page-header-with-icon mg-t" style="text-align:center;">
   <i class="fa-icon-calendar"></i>
   <h2>Calendar</h2>
    </div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
       <div class="center-block text-center datepicker"></div>
     </div>
</div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what should solve your problem. Add it somewhere in your custom stylesheet and change the width % to what suits your design.

```
.datepicker-inline {
 width: 20%;
 }
```

Comment: I believe your solution is to use align attribute for div. Please note that "The <div> align attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead." This line has been taken directly from w3schools. Hence not really recommended. Either use the approach given by @aorfevre or try the css i have given. Both should do the trick for you.